# Weak convergence implies strong convergence in L1 space of functions?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, weak-convergence

Given a sequence of functions of time and space $f_n:[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$. Such that for each $t\in [0,T]$ $f(t)$ converges weakly in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$  to an $f(t) \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Is it true that $f_n$ converges strongly in $L^1([0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^d)$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case where $d = 1$ and $f_n(x,t) = \sin(nx) 1_{[0,\pi]}$. Note that each $f_n$ is constant in $t$.

By the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma $f_n(t)$ converges weakly to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. However a simple calculation shows that the $L^1$-norm does not converge to $0$.